# Nested absolute menus get cut by overflow

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple floating menu with the following shape:
[image]
The big menu should be with an absolute position, and so as the sub menu for each item.
Also, the big menu must be at most 180px, and if it's content needs more space, it should have a scrollbar.
My attempt:

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
div.menu {
   max-height: 180px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: visible;
   width: 250px;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   padding: 5px;
   position: absolute;

}
div.sub-menu {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 1;
}
div.sub-toggle {
    position: relative;
}
div.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

class Menu extends React.Component {
    state = {
    show: false,
    showSub: -1
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }

  toggleSub(i) {
    this.setState({ showSub: i })
  }

  renderItem(i) {
        return (
        <div className='item' key={i}>
          <span>item {i}</span>
        <div className='sub-toggle'>
                  <button onClick={() => this.toggleSub(i)}>sub</button>
        {
            this.state.showSub === i &&
          <div className='sub-menu'>
            <div>sub 1</div>
            <div>sub 2</div>
            <div>sub 3</div>
          </div>
        }
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>
        {
            this.state.show &&
           <div className='menu'>
            {new Array(10).fill().map((x, i) => this.renderItem(i))}
          </div>
        }
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className='wrapper'><Menu /></div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9zy7cx3m/4/

The problem is that the sub menu is being cut off by the overflow.

Is there a way to achieve my goal without using DOM maniuplations (pure CSS with maybe some changes of DOM hierarchies?)? if not, what could be the best solution?
(I thought about making a "global" sub menu and change it's absolute position according to the pressed item).

For what is worth, I am using React.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be obvious you can't hide ***and*** show overflowing contents at the same time. That's why you want to get the small one out of the big one, wrap both inside a common parent, which would have the necessary right padding to accommodate the small one (which you probably want with `position:absolute`, while the common ancestor would have `position:relative`).

Comment: or use fixed positioning on the small child and keep its position updated on scroll. (not as easy of a solution, but you dont have a parent with extra padding blocking the UI this way)